# WSO2 Identity Server setting a user to "inactive"

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way to inactivate a user in WSO2 identity server 5.0.0?
Inactivating should mean that the user cannot login to other applications which are SSO integrated into the IS.
Removing roles/permissions seems not to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 IS supports account lock feature to cater your requirement from IS 4.5.0 onwards. Please follow this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=34612027).

Account disable functionality is not yet implemented and we have already reported a [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3286) to track it in future releases.

Comment: I haven't seen the jira task for it before. Thanks. I configured the accoount locking feature with 5.1.0 M6 successfully, but failed to get it working with 5.0.0 . Has anyone see that working on 5.0.0?